# Weird behaviour: JS for loop i<=20 sometimes outputs 15 as the final entry, with 0-20 displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, random, iterator

I've set up a simple for loop, outputting random numbers. For some reason, this code sometimes outputs 15 as the final value of "i", with the previous ones 0-20 displaying correctly.

Here's a screenshot of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUjZO.png

```js
var picks = 20;
var numberRange = 1000;

for(var i = 0; i<=picks; ++i) {
 var rnd = ~~(Math.random()*numberRange)+1;
 console.log(i + ":\t" + rnd);
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* it might be your console.

Comment: I've run that program in Node about 20 times and it never does that.

Comment: I suspect you might be playing a joke with people :) code is fine and has no way of breaking

Comment: I tried your code and it's working perfectly!

Comment: Just created a fiddle that runs it 10000 times... never happens http://jsfiddle.net/abwoj616/

Comment: manually ran this 100 times through Chrome Developer Tools, cannot duplicate the problem